# Разбиение js-скрипта с использованием backbone.js на файлы

Tags: html, backbone.js, javascript

Есть страница index.html, из нее посылаются запросы к сервису, вся логика происходит на одной странице, для этого использую backbone.js. На странице есть скрипт, в котором заключена логика работы с backbone.js. Нужно разделить скрипт на файлы(app.js, authorization.js, register.js, profile.js), каждая из 3 view должна быть описана в отдельном файле. У меня не получается это сделать, проблема в видимости объектов.. Я мало знаком с js. Помогите правильно разделить скрипт, заранее спасибо!
Файл index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>My Client Application</title>
<link href="/jsapp/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/jsapp/css/my.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/jsapp/js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="/jsapp/js/libs/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="/jsapp/js/libs/backbone.js"></script>
<script type="text/template" id="register">
        <div id="register">
            <h2>Регистрация</h2>
            <br />
            <span>Имя:</span>
            <br />
            <input type="text" id="FirstName" />
            <br />
            <span>Фамилия:</span>
            <br />
            <input type="text" id="LastName" />
            <br />
            <span>Логин:</span>
            <br />
            <input type="text" id="rLogin" />
            <br />
            <span>Пароль:</span>
            <br />
            <input type="password" id="rPassword" />
            <br />
            <span>Повтор пароля:</span>
            <br />
            <input type="password" id="ReplayPassword" />
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="Зарегистрироваться" />
        </div>
</script>
<script type="text/template" id="login">
        <div id="login">
            <h2>Авторизация</h2>
            <br />
            <span>Логин:</span>
            <br />
            <input type="text" id="lLogin" />
            <br />
            <span>Пароль:</span>
            <br />
            <input type="password" id="lPassword" />
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="Войти" />
            <input type="button" value="Регистрация" />
        </div>
</script>
<script type="text/template" id="profile">
        <div id="profile">
            Пользователь
            <br/>
          <%= userName %>
            <br/>
            <a href="#!/">Назад</a>
        </div>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#!/">Авторизация</a>
    <a href="#!/register">Регистрация</a>
</div>
<br />
<div align="center" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div id="block" class="block">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var AppState = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            userName: "user"
        }
    });
    var appState = new AppState();

    var Controller = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "": "login",
            "!/": "login",
            "!/profile": "profile",
            "!/register": "register"
        },
        login: function () {
            if (Views.authorizeView != null) {
                Views.authorizeView.render();
            }
        },
        profile: function () {
            if (Views.profileView != null) {
                Views.profileView.render();
            }
        },
        register: function () {
            if (Views.registerView != null) {
                Views.registerView.render();
            }
        },
    });
    var controller = new Controller();
    var AuthorizeView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#block"),
        template: _.template($('#login').html()),

        events: {
            "click input[value='Войти']:button": "login",
            "click input[value='Регистрация']:button": "goregister"
        },

        login: function () {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:55254/api/user/?login=' + $('#lLogin').val() +    '&password=' + $('#lPassword').val(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != "null") {
                        localStorage.Token = data;
                        //////////////////
                        $.ajax({
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: 'GET',
                            url: 'http://localhost:55254/api/user/',
                            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                                xhr.setRequestHeader('Token', localStorage.Token);
                            },
                            success: function (name) {
                                appState.set({
                                    "userName": name
                                });
                            }
                        });
                        controller.navigate("!/profile", true);
                        //////////////////
                    } else {
                        alert('Такой пользователь не существует.');
                    }
                }
            });

        },

        goregister: function () {
            controller.navigate("!/register", true);
        },

        render: function () {
            $(this.el).html(this.template());
            return this;
        }
    });
    var ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#block"),

        template: _.template($('#profile').html()),

        events: {

        },

        initialize: function () {
            this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
        },

        render: function () {
            $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });
    var RegisterView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#block"),

        template: _.template($('#register').html()),

        events: {
            "click input[value='Зарегистрироваться']:button": "register"
        },

        register: function () {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: 'PUT',
                url: 'http://localhost:55254/api/user/?firstName=' + $('#FirstName').val() + '&lastName=' + $('#LastName').val() + '&login=' + $('#rLogin').val() + '&password=' + $('#rPassword').val(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == 'ok') {
                        controller.navigate("!/", true);
                    } else {
                        alert('Ошибка при регистрации.');
                    }
                }
            });
        },

        render: function () {
            $(this.el).html(this.template());
            return this;
        }
    });
    Views = {
        authorizeView: new AuthorizeView(),
        profileView: new ProfileView({ model: appState }),
        registerView: new RegisterView()
    };
    appState.trigger("change");
    Backbone.history.start();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

решил проблему видимости добавив

```
(function () {
window.sample = {};
sample.views = {};
sample.routers = {};
sample.models = {};
sample.templates = {};
})();

  .........

$(document).ready(function () {
     sample.routers.app = new sample.routers.App();
     sample.views.authorizeView = new sample.views.AuthorizeView();
     sample.views.registerView = new sample.views.RegisterView();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

в app.js.

в файлах nameview.js писал:

```
sample.views.AuthorizeView = Backbone.View.extend({
```

файлы скриптов желательно подключать в конце страницы.

может, кому-то это поможет:)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону RequireJS http://requirejs.org/

1) Её использование позволит разбить код на модули и каждый модуль сможет получать доступ только к тем модулям, которые ему необходимы для работы.

2) Шаблоны, которые Вы прячете в script type="text/template" тоже можно будет поместить в отдельные модули-файлы.

3) Потом все эти модули (включая шаблоны) можно "скомпилировать" в один единый js-файл (и сжать его, если нужно) и подключить его на страницу.

Разработка при модульном подходе упростится в разы.